# Disable ido-use-filename-at-point under specific cases

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs to code in Verilog/SystemVerilog and the commented lines begin with `//`.

I like to use the "ido find files at point" and so I have `'(ido-use-filename-at-point (quote guess))` in `custom-set-variables`.

It works perfectly except when I am trying to open another file while my cursor is on the first word of a comment like `//Revision Control:`. It tries to find a file called Revision in `//` path.

How can I disable the ido ffap functionality for the root `/` and `//` paths? Another way that would serve the functionality is if the ido ffap disables automatically on lines starting with `//`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no special ffap-handlers for `verilog-mode` yet in `ffap-alist` the following code should do the trick:

```
(defun ffap-verilog (name)
  (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t) ;; string-match should not change match data
    (ppss (syntax-ppss)))
    (if (and (eq (syntax-ppss-context ppss) 'comment) ;; we are inside a comment
         (= (line-number-at-pos (nth 8 ppss)) (line-number-at-pos (point))) ;; limit the match to the line starting the comment
         (string-match "/[/*]\\([[:alnum:]_.]\\)+$"
               (buffer-substring-no-properties (nth 8 ppss) (point))))
    ""
      name)))


(add-to-list 'ffap-alist '(verilog-mode . ffap-verilog) 'append)
```

The special case is checked that the leading `//` or `/*` of a comment is directly followed by a string which could be miss-interpreted by `ffap` as an url or a path with wildcard. Note however, that other strings inside of a comment starting with `\\` are not handled since these could really be urls.